# 90s (or earlier) movie with experimental, invisible, teleporting, time-traveling ship

Tags: story-identification, movie

So, I watched this in 1996 and thought it was pretty good, and now I want to find its title so I can rewatch it!

There's an experiment with a ship in order to make it completely invisible. Unfortunately, that experiment goes wrong and the ship ends up far in the future where the experiment has been started up again. This future experiment caused the ship from the past to teleport into the future. At random intervals, the ship teleports to a random place in the world and puts everyone in danger of dying because of it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*The Philadelphia Experiment* (1984)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087910/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt):

> In 1943, the United States tests an anti-radar system to make the U.S. Navy ships invisible to the enemy. Dr. James Longstreet uses his experiment in the destroyer escort USS Eldridge that disappears from Philadelphia. The sailors David Herdeg and his best friend Jim Parker are projected to 1984, where they meet Allison Hayes. They unsuccessfully try to contact their base and out of the blue Jimmy disappears in a hospital. Allison helps David to visit Jimmy's wife Pamela, but Jimmy refuses to see him. Now David's only hope is meeting Dr. James Longstreet to learn what to do. Will he be well succeeded?

For the record, this is loosely based on the real-life rumors of a ["Philadelphia Experiment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia_Experiment) according to which a U.S. Navy ship had successfully been rendered undetectable.

---

Found with the Google query `movie experiment invisible time travel ship site:imdb.com/title`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so glad that I'll be able to rewatch this now!

Comment: @InventPalooza you're welcome, enjoy the rewatch! :D